# Publishing to IIS from Visual Studio Not Transforming web.config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, deployment

I've got my web.config.  I have the box on the "Solution Configurations" set to Release, and what I've done is modify web.release.config to look like this (actual connection details redacted of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=mysite.com;Database=mydb;uid=myuser;pwd=mypassword;"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
   <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The connectionString that I added, however, does not get included whenever I use the publish feature to put it up on my production server.  Any suggestions on some critical step I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the transformation in your element. Add `xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)"` in the `add` element. Check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) reference.